# ActionEvent button - TextField JavaFX

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, textfield

Hi everyone I need to create an ActionEvent from a button and put the button name on a TextField. What i have is a kind of calculator but when I press a button doesn't fills the TextField. As an example what I want: I have the numer one on a button and when I press it the number one appears on the TextField. This is what I have until now:

**AppCalculator class:**

```
package appcalculator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AppCalculator extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

**FXMLDocumentController:**

```
package appcalculadora;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {


TextField texto = new TextField();


@FXML
private void btnOne(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("1");

}

@FXML
private void btnTwo(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("2");
}

@FXML
private void btnThree(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("3");
}

@FXML
private void btnFour(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("4");
}

@FXML
private void btnFive(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("5");
}

@FXML
private void btnSix(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("6");
}

@FXML
private void btnSevent(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("7");
}

@FXML
private void btnEight(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("8");
}

@FXML
private void btnNine(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("9");
}

@FXML
private void btnZero(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("0");
}

@FXML
private void btnPoint(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText(".");
}

@FXML
private void btnPlus(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("+");
}

@FXML
private void btnMinus(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("-");
}

@FXML
private void btnBy(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("*");
}

@FXML
private void btnDivided(ActionEvent event) {
    texto.setText("/");
}

@FXML
private void btnErrase(ActionEvent event){
    texto.deletePreviousChar();
}

@FXML
private void btnTotal(ActionEvent event){
    texto.getText();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

}
```

**And my respective FXML document**

Comment: Where is the FXML? `texto` never seems to be displayed in the UI anywhere, so it is no surprise if you don't see any result of pressing the buttons.

Comment: Also, instead of having so many private methods you could make one method to handle most buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you with your answer. Like @James_D you are missing '@FXML private TextField texto;.' Also, you could probably get rid of most of your methods.

Here is a sample program:

> Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication58 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private TextField texto;


    //Use this approach to replace most of your private button handlers!
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Button button = (Button)event.getSource();
        texto.appendText(button.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
    }      
}
```

> FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="javafxapplication58.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="btnOne" layoutX="126" layoutY="90" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="1" />
      <Button fx:id="btnTwo" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="90.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="2" />
      <TextField fx:id="texto" layoutX="86.0" layoutY="43.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

String x = TextFieldName.getText();
if(e.getSource() == ButtonName)
TextFieldName.setText("");
```